# Getting undeclared identified error in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to fill an array with variables from other header files. But I am getting a undefined identifier message.

Here are the 2 header files for example:

Header file with the variable bsnstem which is getting undefined identifier on the header file with the array:

```
// Declareren
string stm;
int bsnstem;
string dststem;

// Prototype
void InvoerenStemmer();
void WeergevenStemmer();

// Implementatie
void InvoerenStemmer()
{
    cout << "Voer je stemmersnaam in : \n";
    cin >> stm;
    cout << "Voer je BSN in : \n";
    cin >> bsnstem;
    cout << "Voer je district in : \n";
    cin >> dststem;
    system("PAUSE");
}

void WeergevenStemmer()
{
    cout << "Stemmer " << stm << " met het burgerservicenummer " << bsnstem << " woont in het district " << dststem;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Header file with the array:

```
// Declareren
int bsnstem_bsnkan_vjr[2];

// Prototype 
void InvoerenVerkiezingsjaar();
void WeergevenVerkiezingsjaar(int[]);

// Implementatie
void InvoerenVerkiezingsjaar()
{
    bsnstem_bsnkan_vjr[0] = bsnstem;
    bsnstem_bsnkan_vjr[1] = bsnkan;

    cout << "Voer het verkiezingsjaar in : \n";
    cin >> bsnstem_bsnkan_vjr[2];
    system("PAUSE");
}

void WeergevenVerkiezingsjaar(int bsnstem_bsnkan_vjr[])
{
    cout << "Burgerservicenummer " << bsnstem_bsnkan_vjr[0] << " stemt op burgerservicenummer " << bsnstem_bsnkan_vjr[1] << " in het verkiezingsjaar " << bsnstem_bsnkan_vjr[2];
    system("pause");
}
```

Header file with variable `bsnkan`

```
// Declareren
string knd;
int bsnkan;
string org;
string dstkan;

// Prototype
void InvoerenKandidaat();
void WeergevenKandidaat();

// Implementatie
void InvoerenKandidaat()
{
    cout << "Voer je kandidaatnaam in : \n";
    cin >> knd;
    cout << "Voer je BSN in : \n";
    cin >> bsnkan;
    cout << "Voer je organisatie in : \n";
    cin >> org;
    cout << "Voer je district in : \n";
    cin >> dstkan;
    system("PAUSE");
}

void WeergevenKandidaat()
{
    cout << "Kandidaat " << knd << " met burgerservicenummer " << bsnkan << " van de organisatie " << org << " woon in het district " << dstkan;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Error message:

```
1>d:\persoonlijk\documenten\visual studio 2015\projects\8\12\stemmen.h(16): error C2065: 'bsnstem': undeclared identifier
1>d:\persoonlijk\documenten\visual studio 2015\projects\8\12\stemmen.h(17): error C2065: 'bsnkan': undeclared identifier
```

Comment: Note that `cin >> bsnstem_bsnkan_vjr[2]` will write to the *third* element of an array with only two elements.

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message

Comment: Also please edit your question to include the *full* error message, complete and without editing. Including any possible informational notes. Also please add e.g. a comment on the line(s) where you get the error(s).

Comment: Include the file?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, did edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

you forget to include your headers

```
#include path/yourheadername.h
```